# Smart file copy with hard links

Tags: hard-drive, transfer

I might be getting a new backup hard drive to store all my files in the future, and will be transferring from my old one. But, the thing is that the old one has a lot of duplicate files which are hard linked, and may contain some that are not. To save more space and ensure that everything gets copied (since copying the drive without hard links may cause it to run out of space), I want to recursively copy everything from Drive A to Drive B, except analyze every file that's being copied and get the hash sum. If the file that's currently being copied has the same hash as one that was already copied, create a hard link to that file instead of copying it over again. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Usually I sync big amounts (about 100 Gb) of data with [FreeFileSync](https://www.freefilesync.org/).

It uses database with timestamps, filesizes and checksums. First synchronization takes long time, but next will be faster.

It handles [symbolic links](https://www.freefilesync.org/manual.php?topic=comparison-settings).

[image]

You can start with *File time and size* and *Two Way* synchronization and then solve found conflicts manually.